# Problems getting SQL Server 2005 Project REAL to work in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm learning how to use SQL Server 2008's Analysis Services, and discovered [Microsoft's Project Real](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/project-real.aspx). It looks like a great way to learn how to use Business Intelligence Tools on a real-world example.

Unfortunately, Project REAL's use SQL Server 2005 databases, and I get an error message when I try to attach them using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio: "Unable to open the physical file. Operating system error 5: Failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105".

Has anyone managed to get Project REAL working with SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Operating system error 5 on Windows (or DOS) is 'access denied', as the error tells you ('unable to open physical file'). Where did you put the database? Also, you may want to look for AdventureWorks; there's a version for SQL Server 2008, and it demos BI.

Comment: The database is located in a folder on my local harddrive. Running as Administrator solved the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to run SSMS as Adminstrator (i.e. "Run as Administrator"). Then you have permission to attach databases.